# build fail error while I'm trying to deploy my application in eclipse using azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I'm trying to deploy my application in to azure using eclipse but I'm getting build fail C:\Users\miracle\workspace13\helloworld_onAzure\package.xml:156: Azure SDK v2.4 or later is not installed after

Comment: What version of the Azure SDK do you have installed?

Comment: I have install v2.6
when I was trying to run again I'm getting new error

The cloud source of this component (http://azure.azulsystems.com/zulu/zulu1.8.0_31-8.5.0.1-win64.zip?eclipse) is not available, so it cannot be deployed.

Comment: Thank u sir I have resolved the problem of cloud source component by downloading zip file and re installing my SDK, now I'm able to create an application for Azure using Eclipse